# How to choose a location for rocket launching?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, satellites

What's the relation of earth's magnetic equator with satellite launching? How does the nearness of a rocket launching station to the earth's magnetic equator [make it an ideal location for scientists to conduct atmospheric research?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumba_Equatorial_Rocket_Launching_Station)

But not all stations are near the magnetic equator. why?

Are there any special requirements(in terms of geometry) that are taken into consideration before setting a rocket station?

Answer (score 6):

Since this is a homework question I can't answer it outright for you. But here are things to think about:

To go to space, the rocket needs to go quickly. Fuel is heavy and expensive. How does that influence the location of the launch?

Of the space launching countries, where are they located?

Those are the real core questions you need to answer. The math will show what locations are better than others while geopolitics will explain why not every launch is from the same locations.

Comment: gravity is less at equator.

Comment: [This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rocket_launch_sites) gives list of rocket launching countries and m not seeing any pattern in their location. North latitude varies from 2N to 80N

Comment: @Ramit The pattern has more to do with their national borders and who their allies and enemies are than anything else. It's difficult for Russia to have an equatorial launch pad unless one was built in Cuba. But the USA took a firm stance against Russian rockets in Cuba. Like I said, geopolitics is what matters there more than what is optimal launch position.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misconception that when launching a rocket into orbit you have to accelerate it vertically. A satellite requires an orbital (i.e. tangential) velocity given by:

$$ v \approx \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}} $$

where $M$ is the Earth's mass and $r$ is the distance from the Earth's centre. If you consider, for example, a GPS satellite with an altitude of about 20,000 km from the ground the orbital speed is about 14,000 km/hour. So to get it into a stable orbit you need to accelerate it sideways, not vertically.

Because the Earth rotates, any point on the Earth already has a tangential velocity, and this velocity varies from zero at the North and South pole to about 1,700 km/hour at the equator. The higher the tangential velocity at the launch site the less you need to boost the rocket's speed and the less fuel it will use. So it's better to launch rockets from the equator than from the North pole.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I guess tangential velocity would be maximum at geographical equator and not at magnetic equator. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Ramit: yes, it's the geographical equator that matters, although in practice there isn't much difference. The variation of tangential velocity with latitude is smallest at the equator so small deviations from it don't make much difference.

Comment: This is correct for satellites bound for eastward orbits, which is most of them.  For polar orbits, the rotational velocity can be a detriment and launch sites near the poles would be preferable.  This applies especially to earth observation satellites, which are often in slightly retrograde orbits to be sun synchronous-coming over each part of the earth at the same local solar time.